# Staggering giants with Unrelenting Force

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For some reason I am not able to stagger giants while trying the first version of this shout. I hear the word and see the blue light that appears but nothing happens to my enemy. I tried this on Anise and it works but not on a giant. I should also mention that I havent gone to Hrothgar or Ivarstead yet. Are giants resistant somehow or is there something I need to get from the Greybeards before this will work on everyone?

Comment: Working as intended. Fus alone is weaksource.

Comment: If the only shout you know is Fus, then stay the hell away from Giants. Unless you want to see Skyrim from 200 feet in the air.

Comment: Which, to be fair, is lovely.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To stagger giants, learn and use more words from the Unrelenting force shout. The word Fus alone produces the same effect on giants as a gentle puff of air.

Answer (score -1):

just using "fus" will not work at all. "fus ro" will stagger it. "fus ro dah" will make it go flying backwards.